# centos single domain multiple server

Tags: centos, cluster, lamp

I have a secondary development wordpress site. (Centos 6.6 x86 ,LAMP) Since the size of the site is growing. (300GB+). Now I have 3 server totally.

domain: www.example.com

```
server1  172.192.22.01  /var/www/public_html
                                            /music
                                            /video


server2  172.192.22.02  /var/www/public_html
                                            /article
                                            /photo

server3  172.192.22.03  /var/www/public_html 
                                           /products
                                           /showroom
```

Now 3 ips are setting in domain DNS. I can access `www.example.com/music` but when i cannot accesss `www.example.com/article` or `www.example.com/products`.

`The requested URL /article was not found on this server.`

How to configure so that it could access automaticlly.

```
www.mydomain.com/music/xxx mapping to server with 172.192.22.01
www.mydomain.com/article/xxx mapping to server with 172.192.22.02
www.mydomain.com/products/xxx mapping to server with 172.192.22.03
```

Proxy? Shared folder? Or cluster? I have read many articles, and tried many ways, but still not working for me.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve by splitting things up ?

Comment: @Iain,  I have tried `heatbeat`, but it seems only support 2 server cluster. then install `percona`, it conflict with mysql server. As you, what is the easy way to solve my situation? thanks.

Comment: Please answer the question I asked.

Comment: @Iain, sorry, my english is not well, i tried to translate your question in google. I am putting different folder in different server.(folder music just exist in server1) . but I have copied 3 wordpress files in 3 servers (and configure same .htacesss, same httpd.conf, ServerName www.example.com:80)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking (& assuming I've understood the problem correctly) you could solve this situation nicely with a reverse proxy. I've used Apache in this way in the the past & it worked very well. So the problem you have is that you would like to access transparently three servers over one domain. Or to put it another way, you are trying to balance the load on the domain. Have a look at these how tos. They explain better than I can.

http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: thanks a help. but `yum install -y build-essential` no packege availible

Comment: God...No more respond. your article not working for me, but the "reverse proxy" in english, which help me searched in google. finally I found some tutorial which works in my LAMP condition.